# Create a linechart in PowerBI with multiple lines each based on a type

Tags: charts, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzVLx.png)

I have my table similar to this in the pic. I want to create a linechart in PowerBI such that it contains one line for each type (A,B,C,D) with there values from the value column

is it possible to do that without making any change to the original table?

Comment: Add the types the legend, it will split down the data

Comment: @Jon thanks, this did the trick